# Зерновых культур намолочено (или намолочена) 1 тыс. тонн. - как правильно писать?

Tags: орфография

Зерновых культур намолочено (или намолочена) 261 тыс. тонн. - как правильно писать? ( а если 1 тыс. тонн) - намолочена или намолочено,

Answer (score 1):

При управляемом имени в форме винительного падежа *культур*:

*Зерновых культур намолочено 261 тыс. тонн.*

> Управляемое имя в форме винительного падежа обозначает предмет как
> объект непосредственного приложения того действия или процессуального
> состояния, которое названо глаголом. При установлении обратных,
> противоположных отношений (при конверсии) такой объект оказывается
> субъектом: форма со знач. объекта действия в пассивной конструкции
> обозначает субъект состояния, вызванного этим действием: избрать
> (избирать) депутата — депутат избран, избирается; написать (писать)
> письмо — ***письмо написано***.